# Is the third htmlspecialchars parameter ($encoding) case-sensitive?

Tags: php, case-sensitive, htmlspecialchars

I came across a user-contributed note (upvoted 7 times) on the PHP manual page for [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/function.htmlspecialchars.php) that has me confused.

> Be careful, the "charset" argument IS case sensitive. This is counter-intuitive and serves no practical purpose because the HTML spec actually has the opposite.

Now, I do realize that there is no difference between ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, UTF-8, cp866, cp1251, cp1252, and KOI8-R for the purposes of `htmlspecialchars`.

But it had me wondering about `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode` since they have the same parameters. I'm on PHP 5.3 where the default is ISO-8859-1. I did some testing with Windows-1252, windows-1252, UTF-8, and utf-8. In all cases, I got the expected results for characters that only exist in the tested character set.

So then I wondered whether or not the note

- applies only to certain versions
- applies only to htmlspecialchars
- is wrong

I tried digging into the source, but couldn't find my way around. I'm mainly concerned with the behavior of `html_entity_decode` across different versions because I use this to convert user-supplied HTML to plain text.

Comment: See [html.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/html.c#L377). Looks like it's using `strncasecmp`; thus not case-sensitive. The comment might be very valid for older versions though.